# Score equivalence Oracle Text / Lucene

Tags: oracle, lucene

Is there an equivalence between the scores an Oracle Text Score would calculate and a Lucene one ?
Would you be able to mix the sources to get one unified resultset through the score ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scores are not comparable between queries or data changes in Lucene, much less being comparable to another technology.  Lucene scores of the same document can be changed dramatically by having other documents added or removed from the index.  Scoring as a percentage of maximum becomes the obvious solution, but the same problems remain, as well as that other algorithms in another technology will ikely render different distribution.  You can read about why you should not compare scores like this [here](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ScoresAsPercentages) and [here](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.lucene.user/12076)

A way I managed to lash something similar together was to fetch matches from the other data source, and create a temporary index in a [RAMDirectory](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/store/RAMDirectory.html), and then search again incorporating it with a [MultiSearcher](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/MultiSearcher.html).  That way everything is getting scored on a single, cohesive data set, within a single search.  Scoring should be reasonable enough, though this isn't exactly the most efficient way to search.